# Set the timezone on parse (Objective C)

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, nsdate

My code in Xcode is:

```
NSDate *date = [orderObject objectForKey:@"orderDate"];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.YYYY"];

NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
_orderDate.text = dateString;
```

But when I make an order parse update it with the UTC Timezone and my timezone is UTC-6.

[image: IMAGE PARSE]

Comment: `NSDateFormatter` should default to the current timezone. Have you tried setting the timeZone property explicitly? Have you checked that the current time zone (`[NSTimeZone localTImeZone]`) is indeed UTC-6?

Answer (score 0):

Set [timeZone](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSDateFormatter/timeZone) for NSDateFormatter

More info: [Technical Q&A QA1480 “NSDateFormatter and Internet Dates”.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1480/_index.html)